# How to create a composite score composed of variables with different levels of measurement?

Tags: composite

For my graduation research, I am trying to create a composite score about household resilience out of data collected through a household survey. However, this data consists of ordinal variables (5-point Likert scale), binary variables (yes-no questions), and ratio variables (in proportions between 0-1).

My plan was to recode the data on the 5-point Likert scale into scores from 0-1 and do the same for the yes-no questions, with yes = 1 and no = 0 (since answering yes would mean a household is more resilient and thus have a higher score). However, this seems very off.

At this moment I am aware that it wasn't the best idea to create a survey with both types of questions, but I am unable to recollect the data.

Therefore my **question** is as follows: do you have any tips on how to create a composite score composed of both interval and binary variables?

Thank you in advance and have a lovely day.

Best,
Nina